# How to render or go to a page loaded via an angular $http.get call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an authentication provider injected into my angular app such that all $http calls get the proper auth headers set on them.

I'd like to have a link or a button that loads an entirely different page than the app, but also utilizes the authentication headers that are automatically set in $http.get, etc.   Unfortunately, straight `<a href="/some/url/that/needs/auth.html">link</a>` doesn't get the headers set from angular automatically.

If I call `$http.get("/some/url/that/needs/auth.html")`, the response contains the actual html, but I don't know how to render it.   (I've only ever used this to get json data to render in the angular app, no idea if it can be used to render a page).

What would be the best way to do this?

edit:  I don't want to render partials/templates.   I want to load an entire page starting with `<html>...`

Comment: I have never actually tried it, but take a look at [$templateRequest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest) and [$templateRequestProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$templateRequestProvider) beacuse I think they might what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$sce` and `ng-bind-html` to render a HTML string in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$scope.html = "<h1>Hello</h1>";
```

and

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="html"></div>
```

---

For Angular 1.x, use `ng-bind-html` in the HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html="thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml"></div>
```

At this point you would get a `attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context` error so you need to either use [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) or [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to resolve that.

#### $sce

Use `$sce.trustAsHtml()` in the controller to convert the html string.

```
 $scope.thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(someHtmlVar);
```

#### ngSanitize

There are 2 steps:

1. include the angular-sanitize.min.js resource, i.e.:
   `<script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>`
2. In a js file (controller or usually app.js), include ngSanitize, i.e.:
   `angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'ngSanitize'])`